# NPM module.js:472

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, npm, node-modules

When I try to start any **npm** command, the terminal displays

```
module.js:472
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:425:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:146:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:540:3
```

I tried to reinstall **node.js** and **npm**.
How and where can I change the directory "usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" to "usr/bin/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js".

p.s. When I copy all node_modules and past to /node_modules/npm/bin/, it works, but this is not an acceptable solution.

Comment: Please share the output for: `npm list -g` and `env | grep -i  node`

Comment: @nehal-j-wani ,  output:luki@luki-350V5C  ~  npm list -g
(same - module.js:472......) 
 luki@luki-350V5C  ~  env | grep -i node
PATH=/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin:/home/luki/bin:/home/luki/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

Comment: Put it on fpaste.org and share link here

Comment: @nehal-j-wani, https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/7HgagPDF0IsuKJi0~9H3FV5M1UNdIGYhyRLivL9gydE=

Comment: In my machine, there is no `node_modules` folder inside `/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin`. Try `rm -fr /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node_modules` and see if the problem persists? Also, why do you have `/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin` in your PATH variable?

Comment: I tried rm - fr ... result -> https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/W71rywrZ-UFDK83GygN0UV5M1UNdIGYhyRLivL9gydE=  , why? i dont know =(

Comment: Hmm... I removed /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin from PATH, and removed nodejs, when i instaled nodejs one more. Result PATH ->  luki@luki-350V5C  ~  env | grep -i node
PATH=/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin:/home/luki/bin:/home/luki/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

Comment: Install nodejs use this command - > curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

Answer (score 0):

In you project folder there is a file named `webpack.local.settings.js.sample`. Rename the file to `webpack.local.settings.js` It worked for me.